# Xtend: declare empty map as return statement

Tags: xtend

In an overridden method I'd like to return an empty map. How I'm trying to make it work:

```
override myMethod() {
    #{} // cannot convert from Map<Object, Object> to Map<String,MyClass>
}
```

And what is working for me but not so "Xtend-ish":

```
override myMethod() {
    Collections.emptyMap // Works
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
override Map<String,MyClass> myMethod() {
    #{}
}
```

Comment: "#{} as Map<String, ValueTypeInfo>" is working as a return statement but actually, I was hoping to get rid of generics and just type some fancy expression.